# Laravel 6: How to pass checkbox value into database user table upon registration

Tags: php, laravel, registration, laravel-6

I have created a registration form using Laravel 6 default migration table and Auth register controller. Now I want to have two types of accounts, so I have a added a checkbox to the HTML form. If the checkbox is checked, the account should be of different type than when the checkbox in unchecked.

- ### What I have:

**Database tables:**

```
account_types (id, name)
users (id, name, email, password, account_type_id)
```

**HTML**

```
<label class="switch">
      <input id="register-toggle-switch" name="account-type" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked onclick="toggleswitch()">
</label>
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
/**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            // 'account_type_id' => ['required']
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['account-type']))
        {
            $account = '1';
        }
        else if(!isset($_POST['account-type']))
        {
            $account = '2';
        }
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'account_type_id' => $account
        ]);
    }
```

---

However this does not work as it returns an error saying:
"General error: 1364 Field 'account_type_id' doesn't have a default value" and then proceeds to show the attempted query which does not include the 'account_type_id' or its value at all.

---

**So the question is:** 
Depending of the state of the checkbox in the form, how can I pass the respective id into the registration query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has mass-assignment protections on its models, which will send no value to the insert query, and thus cause the default value error.  Make sure you tell the **User** model that it's OK to pass `account_type_id` via the `$fillable` variable.

On the **User** model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', ... 'account_type_id'
];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly without any further alterations. However I did add ```$account = null;``` before the ```if``` and ```else if``` conditions as well as right after returning the new user data insertion, to ensure no data is stored in the ```$account``` variable right before and after using it. It works just fine, once again.

Comment: Very glad it helped, Bill.  The null of the `$account` was not the issue - Laravel specifically blocked sending that variable, thus causing the error.  If you want to null it out, that's totally fine, but it wasn't the cause for the error :)  As it is scoped to that method, it will not have a value going in, so no need to null it out really.